# Where does Repo get injected in Phoenix controllers?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This is pretty much a newbie question, so I apologize if the answer should be obvious, but I have been unable to solve it myself for some time now.

I'm following the phoenix book from pragmatic programmers (https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix). Which by looking through the corresponding github repo I believe is written for version 1.1. So far I've been able to make it work through looking at the upgrade instructions etc. But when I got to the part under "Implementing Login and Logout" I am stuck with an error `function Repo.get_by/2 is undefined (module Repo is not available)`.

I've been tracing through the code trying to figure out where Repo should be made available from? The error itself is called in `auth.ex`, but the missing module is passed as an argument from `session_controller.ex`, thus I've included both.

`session_controller.ex` [Link to file in github](https://github.com/RobinTo/phxtutorial/blob/repo_module_missing/lib/rumbl_web/controllers/session_controller.ex)

```
def create(conn, %{"session" => %{"username" => user, "password" => pass}}) do
    case Rumbl.Auth.login_by_username_and_pass(conn, user, pass, repo: Repo) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        ...
      {:error, _reason, conn} ->
        ...
    end
end
```

`auth.ex` [Link to file in github](https://github.com/RobinTo/phxtutorial/blob/repo_module_missing/lib/rumbl_web/controllers/auth.ex)

```
def login_by_username_and_pass(conn, username, given_pass, opts) do
    repo = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
    user = repo.get_by(Rumbl.User, username: username)

    cond do
      user && checkpw(given_pass, user.password_hash) ->
        {:ok, login(conn, user)}
      user ->
        {:error, :unauthorized, conn}
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw()
        {:error, :not_cound, conn}
    end
end
```

I've compared my code to what seems to be the [official repo](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/blob/master/examples/testing_otp/rumbrella/apps/rumbl/web/controllers/), and the only difference I find is that it seems to be phoenix version 1.1.1 rather than 1.3.

Where does Repo come from, and why is it unavailable here? I notice it's available in `call` inside `auth.ex`, but I assume that might be because that is the standard plug function when it's included in the browser pipeline. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either use it’s full name `Rumbl.Repo` or `alias Rumbl` on the top of the file you receive this error. https://github.com/RobinTo/phxtutorial/blob/repo_module_missing/lib/rumbl/repo.ex#L1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your repo `Rumbl.Repo` at `phxtutorial/lib/rumbl/repo.ex`. The problem is that your `SessionController` does not know which `Repo` you are referring to, if you do not alias it, or use the full module name.

What you need to do is alias it into your `SessionController`, like this:

```
defmodule RumblWeb.SessionController do
  use RumblWeb, :controller
  alias Rumbl.Router.Helpers
  alias Rumbl.Repo # This is the new alias

  ...
end
```

Now your `SessionController` knows that the `repo: Repo` you are referring to is the `Rumble.Repo`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. They don't do this in the official repo though, how does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure how the Pragmatic book does it, but usually the controller should not need to know about the repo, but communicates through `Context`. See [`Context`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html).

Comment: By the way... thanks for posting your code repository with the question. Made it a lot easier to debug!

Answer (score 1):

Modules can be globally imported or aliased into controllers, routers, views, etc. via the `web.ex` file. In your project there is a [lib/rumbl_web.ex](https://github.com/RobinTo/phxtutorial/blob/repo_module_missing/lib/rumbl_web.ex) which is doing the imports and aliases.

You could add an alias here and `Repo` would be available in all controllers. Personally, I would not have Repo available in the controllers—they do not need to know about Ecto. I would instead include Repo in each context module. This is better [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Unless a single context function needs to operate on multiple repos, I see no reason for the controller injecting it into the function.

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could define another function in `rumbl_web.ex` for context modules and add to each:

```
use RumblWeb, :context
```

Personally, I just alias in each context module.